# execute sh file with Russian or Chines Chars - Saved as UTF-8 or Unicode

Tags: bash, scripts, locale, encoding

I have a file which has some russian characters in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "s/\bVAR1\b/Привет, как ты/g" file1.txt
```

When I save this file I had to save this as UTF-8 or Unicode format as I have some Unicode characters in the file and I will loose those if I save as ANSI. Once I save the file, when I use the file command I get the below:

```
bash-4.1$ file test.sh
test.sh: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) English text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Question: How can I make this as executable shell script file? I get the below if my file has only English characters:

```
bash-4.1$ file test2.sh
test2.sh: POSIX shell script text executable
```

Comment: What editor are you using? I pasted the above script contents into a file `test.sh` using `cat` and it all works just fine (`file` identifies the script as `test.sh: POSIX shell script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable` and executing `./test.sh` modifies `file.txt` as expected).

Comment: First, what are the permissions of these shell script files? Execute `ls -l test*.sh` and post the output if you don't know what that means.

Comment: Second, to learn about the relation of _Unicode_ and _UTF-8_ I recommend this blog article: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Hi Murphy, Thank for your points. There is no issue with the file permissions..Had to avoid BOM chars and set fileformat=unix if the file was edited using any windows editor tools.